# C/C++ functions tag for Geany Editor

Tags: c++, c, tags, geany

How to generate the C/C++ functions tag for Geany, like those that included in the [archive](http://wiki.geany.org/get_tags), how I can do that. I want to get auto completion when entering a functions name. In the archive there is a files with 'tags' extensions with the following definition of some "C/C++" functions. At the moment I have so many new libraries which is desirable to identify in Geany Editor:

```
# format=tagmanager
@abstractÌ8ÎAlsa.MixerRegistrationOptionsÖ0ÏMixerAbstractionLevel
... (some declarations)
allocÌ128Í(out CardInfo info)ÎAlsa.CardInfoÖ0Ïpublic int
allocÌ128Í(out ElemId eid)ÎAlsa.ElemIdÖ0Ïpublic int
allocÌ128Í(out ElemInfo t)ÎAlsa.ElemInfoÖ0Ïpublic int
```

So my question is - how I can create such file(s) by myself. Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: [**Make a sample in your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25708628/edit) please! I'm not willing to download that stuff, to see what you mean. Other's won't either.

Comment: I won't either, you should really post the relevant passages here

Comment: Add the code into the question by editing, don't put it in comments.

Comment: Great, casting for reopening then. Thanks :)

Comment: unfortunately not, I never used geany I'm sorry